# How to insert Rich Text Format(.rtf) file content into word doc using word javascript API

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am using word javaScript Api for developing a Word add-in, i need to load a file from server and insert the content into the document, currently .docx files are working fine and inserted into the document but when i try to insert a .rtf format file content into a document, word throws below error:

```
Error: {"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"RunMustReturnPromise","message":"The batch function passed to the \".run\" method didn't return a promise. The function must return a promise, so that any automatically-tracked objects can be released at the completion of the batch operation. Typically, you return a promise by returning the response from \"context.sync()\".","traceMessages":[],"debugInfo":{},"stack":"RunMustReturnPromise: The batch function passed to the \".run\" method didn't return a promise. The function must return a promise, so that any automatically-tracked objects can be released at the completion of the batch operation. Typically, you return a promise by returning the response from \"context.sync()\".\n   at t.throwError (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:233250)\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:21:202009)\n   at yi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/word-win32-16.0
```

I am using below code to insert the content:

```
range.insertFileFromBase64(myBase64, Word.InsertLocation.start);
```

Please advice how i can insert the RTF format file content in word document.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a full code snippet?

Comment: I'm researching this. In the meantime, RTF files tend to be much larger than the equivalent docx files and timing issues can affect whether or not you can get away with mishandling your context.sync() calls. Be sure that the Word.run in which you call insertFileFromBase64 has a "return context.sync()" somewhere after the call of insertFileFromBase64. Don't forget that keyword "return". It has to be there.

Comment: @RickKirkham-Microsoft Thanks, i missed the return.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting RTF files is not supported in the API today, please try docx formats.
Btw your error seems to be that you are not calling return context.sync().

Comment: Thanks, i was missing return before context.sync. Is there any way to read RTF and convert the RTF to DOCX or any suggestion how i can manage the RTF files?